# How to achieve scrollableTabRow view but in Column with indicator in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to achieve this view[image] where it must have indicator that slides to tapped item in jetpack compose android.

I was able to create replicate content with lazycolumn but im not able to implement indicator that slides with selection.

I just want this behaviour

Comment: what make an item have the indicator is it a click on it or when it is at the top of the scroll. please provide more info so we can help you

Comment: @AymanAit Yes on click! when we select any item that indicator need to move to that specific item and stick to it until we select different item

Comment: Would navigation rail be a good fit for your use case? https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-rail/overview

Comment: @Abhimanyu but how to have this indicator in navigation rail?

Comment: What happens on click? It is for navigation or filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your requirement and this close i'm able to create!

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun VerticalSlideAnimation() {
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    val slideOffset by animateDpAsState(offset, label = "")
    var indicatorVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val density = LocalDensity.current

    var targetIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val position by remember { derivedStateOf { listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.find { it.key == targetIndex } } }

    LaunchedEffect(position) {
        if (position?.offset != null) {
            indicatorVisibility = true
            offset = with(density) { position?.offset!!.toDp() }
        } else {
            indicatorVisibility = false
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            items(100, key = { it }) { item ->
                Card(onClick = {
                    val itemLayoutInfo = listState.layoutInfo
                        .visibleItemsInfo
                        .find { it.index == item }

                    offset = with(density) {
                        (itemLayoutInfo?.offset ?: 0).toDp()
                    }

                    targetIndex = item
                }) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(56.dp)) {
                        Text(
                            text = item.toString(),
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (indicatorVisibility) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .offset(y = slideOffset)
                    .width(4.dp)
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[look at working result here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLHWn.gif)